# Issues awaiting replies in public channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

The following code is resulting in no errors to the console. After I type the command, the first `message.reply` line executes properly, but the bot doesn't seem to acknowledge someone types 'accept' or 'deny'. Been messing with this for quite a long time. I've done commands like this in private messages and it works. But for some reason since this is in a public channel, it doesn't seem to work.

```js
module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {

  //!endbrawl winner [username] loser [username]

  let messageArray = message.content.split(" ")
  let winner = messageArray[2]
  let loser = messageArray[4]

  message.reply(`${message.author} wants to close this brawl with ${winner} as the victor and ${loser} as the loser. \n ${winner}, do you accept the result? If yes, type 'accept'. If not, type 'deny'.`);
  let winnerUser = message.mentions.users.first();
  let filter = m => m.author.id == winnerUser.id;
  message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
    maxMatches: 1,
  }).then(collected => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (collected.first().content === "accept") {
      return message.reply(`${winner} has accepted the proposed result.`)
      // put in code asking loser to agree with proposed result
    } else if (collected.first().content === "deny") {
      return message.reply(`${winner} has denied the proposed result.`)
    } else {
      return message.reply(`${winner}, your reply was invalid.`)
    }
  })
}
```

I have looked for ways to solve this, but most involve private messaging or what was told doesn't work for me. No errors in any of those attempts. It just seems like it isn't even looking at the replies.

Thanks for any and all help! It is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
    max: 1,
  }).then(...);
```

That `max` means that the maximun number of messages **that will be processed** will be 1: that means that if the next message is not sent by the author the bot will stop listening for new messages. The other message could even be your bot's reply, since you're not waiting for that to be finished before setting the `awaitMessages`.
Try using `maxMatches` instead of `max`.

```
message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
    maxMatches: 1,
  }).then(...);
```

Reference: [`MessageCollectorOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageCollectorOptions)

---

With that said, you want the winner to be able to send that message and so you'll need to change your `filter` function.
You'll first need to get the User object of the winner, then make the `filter` so that it checks for their id.

```
let winnerUser = message.mentions.users.first();
let filter = m => m.author.id == winnerUser.id;
```

You could also match the id from the plain mention, but I find it easier to use the object instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like that did anything to solve the problem. Still no errors in console either. I updated my code above with with your advice. Actually, it works when the author replies with accept, but not the one designated "winner".

Comment: Your filter `const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;` does only allow the author to choose accept or deny

Comment: I am certain that is the problem. What I am unsure of is how to have that filter listen for the user identified as "winner".

Comment: It depends on what is the `[username]` argument: is it a @mention, a plain tag#1234, or just the plain username?

Comment: It is a mention.

Comment: Still isn't reacting correctly with that. I'm at a loss as to what is wrong.

Comment: More specifically, it isn't throwing errors nor is it responding to replies. Actually, the bot gives no chance to actually reply. It instantly jumps to "(winner), (loser) Your reply was invalid" after using the command. I don't have it set to use both names in that line so something is wrong. I edited my code above to what I am currently using.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the arguments are not parsed well, but it seems like everything is ok... I really don't know what to do without any further clue :\ (btw, when you add code, do not use snippets since Node.js code is not executable in the browser: use the `{}` button instead ;))